# Subclass of UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uitextfield

I want to subclass UITextField and have a method that sets the maximum number of characters. allowed. In the init method of this subclass I try setting the inputDelegate to self but the callbacks aren't triggered. Also this is an iOS 5 thing only. My question is what protocol or notification would allow me to fire an event when a key is tapped so that I don't have to implement the UITextField delegate in my view controller to achieve this limit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this, create a delegate class for you textfield

.m file

```
@implementation LimitedTextFieldDelegate

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(textField.text.length >= 5 && ![string isEqualToString:@""])
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
@end
```

.h file

```
@interface LimitedTextFieldDelegate : UITextField<UITextFieldDelegate>
@end
```

in the UITextField subclass do the following

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        //limitedDelegate is a property of your textfield subclass
        self.limitedDelegate = [[LimitedTextFieldDelegate alloc] init];
        self.delegate = self.limitedDelegate;
    }
    return self;


}
```

Comment: But what if you implement the delegate in your ViewController as well?I.e. will this implementation not override what you have in LimitedTextField?

Comment: YOu could add a delegate to limited textfield itself, to route the callbacks to the viewcontroller itself.